# Run QGIS script without going through QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, line

I have the following script that I'd like to run without using QGGIS. Is there a way to do that?

```
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

input_point=r'C:\Users\Dylan\Desktop\Testing\Points2lines\Tracks.shp'
output_line=r'C:\Users\Dylan\Desktop\Testing\Points2lines\TracksLines.shp'
processing.run("qgis:pointstopath",{'INPUT':input_point,'ORDER_FIELD':'DateTime','OUTPUT':output_line, 'GROUP_FIELD':'RUNLINE_ID'})
```

When I try to run it I have the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'processing'

Thnaks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "using QGIS"? You will need QGIS installed to run this, but you don't need to have a QGIS session running to run this once you've got a few things set up. But it will always be "using QGIS" since the `processing` module is part of QGIS.

Comment: I made a code to create a point shapefile from a csv file. I would like to add to that script a code to create a line shapefile as output, without opening the file in QGIS and running the points2path tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the PATh to the processing framework, since it is a PLUGIN.
See this code below for a standalone processing script, which will do the job. You have to ajust the different path expressions to your system:

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
import sys

#path to your qgis installation
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis", True)
gui_flag = False
app = QgsApplication([], gui_flag)
app.initQgis()

# Add the path to Processing framework: it is a QGIS PLUGIN!
sys.path.append(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins')

# Import and initialize Processing framework
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import processing

input_point=r'C:\tonne\Tracks.shp'
output_line=r'C:\tonne\TracksLines.shp'
processing.run("qgis:pointstopath",{'INPUT':input_point,'ORDER_FIELD':'DateTime','OUTPUT':output_line, 'GROUP_FIELD':'RUNLINE_ID'})

app.exitQgis()
```

To use this script you can start it from a BAT file setting all the other path variables to QGIS with this command:

```
"C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python-qgis.bat" process1.py
```

where process1.py is the script above, the path to the python-qgis.bat must be adapted to your system.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your reply. However I tried to use the script but I have the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis'. 

Should I change something else? 

I just started using python, so sorry for the dumb questions.

Comment: You have to run it from the above BAT file or sys command: "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python-qgis.bat" process1.py - The python-qgis.bat will set all the path variable, that your script will find qgis. Without that, the error you described will appear.